# Django url with parameters in template in multiple lines

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have this type of url in my template:

```
<a href="{% url 'company-detail' region=ownership.company.city.province.region.slug province=ownership.company.city.province.slug city=ownership.company.city.slug company=ownership.company.slug %}">
```

That is, as you can see, monstrously long.

There is some way to do the same thing in multiple lines?

Something like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'company-detail'
            region=ownership.company.city.province.region.slug
            province=ownership.company.city.province.slug
            city=ownership.company.city.slug
            company=ownership.company.slug %}">
```

Comment: In this case, you could define a `get_absolute_url` method for your `Company` model. Then your template would simplify to `<a href="{{ ownership.company.get_absolute_url }}">`

Comment: @Alasdair You are the best! I really didn't know about this solution at all, you solved my day!

Answer (score 0):

```
{% with region=ownership.company.city.province.region.slug province=ownership.company.city.province.slug city=ownership.company.city.slug company=ownership.company.slug %}
<a href="{% url 'company-detail' region province city company %}">
{% endwith %}
```

you can do this

Comment: who is splitting?? it has spaces, not multiple lines

Comment: yeah maybe, ;) problem with so, ;)

Comment: This can't be the correct solution as I am only moving the problem from the href to the with tag! (now the tag is too long)